# How to get around 'Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked'

Tags: mysql, trigger

In MariaDB/MySQL I am looking to create a trigger that automatically changes a boolean to true when 4 Users are a part of it. The issue is I am running a running a query on the table that is being changed (although only the trigger modifies it)

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trg_rso_approval
    AFTER INSERT
    ON RsoUsers
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE num_active_users INT;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_active_users FROM RsoUsers WHERE rsoID = NEW.rsoID;
    IF num_active_users = 4 THEN
        UPDATE Rso SET approval = TRUE WHERE id = NEW.rsoID;
    END IF;
END //
```

When adding a 4th User

```
INSERT INTO RsoUsers (studentID, rsoID)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM User WHERE email = 'janedoe@example.com'), (SELECT id FROM Rso WHERE name = 'Chess Club'));
```

fails with this error

```
Can't update table 'Rso' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

but this succeeds

```
SET @test = (SELECT id FROM Rso WHERE name = 'Chess Club');

INSERT INTO RsoUsers (studentID, rsoID)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM User WHERE email = 'janedoe@example.com'), @test);
```

I have tried BEFORE INSERT as well. Is there any way I can make this work without creating another table?

Comment: You want to alter the values in the rows other than inserted one? Noway - this cannot be performed by the trigger. No variants. Use stored procedure instead of single INSERT, and realize all needed logic in it. From the other side you may easily check the amount of rows per group while retrieving the information about this group, and you don't need in special column for these purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't perform an `UPDATE` on an `INSERT`; change the value, something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_rso_approval
    AFTER INSERT
    ON RsoUsers
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT NEW.approval = 
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_active_users FROM RsoUsers WHERE rsoID = NEW.rsoID ) = 4;
END //
```